# Package manager for AIX

Tags: package-management, aix

While installing Subversion on AIX (version 7.1) from [the official site](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#aix), there are dependencies I need to resolve first before I can proceed to install the subversion package. While installing the dependencies package, there are a bunch of other dependencies package are needed to be download and install as well.

Is there a program for AIX that could automate the installation process? Something like `apt-get` on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [place](http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php?n=Main.HomePage). No as comfortable as apt but nevertheless.

Answer (score 3):

There is no package manager as such for AIX right now. You can try installing RPMs from IBM's website:

http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/toolbox/alpha.html

To install: rpm -i .rpm

If there are dependencies again, search for the package in the above link, download it and install them and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are filesets and rpm packages available for the user to download and then install them using "installp" or "rpm" command. So Unless you use "SUMA" to automatically upgrade the packages, there aren't online repositories available to directly install the packages but you will have to download them explicitly and then install them.

If you want the dependencies to get resolved as well then you can go in for "installp -g" command to install the fileset with dependencies but then you will have to make sure that the filesets are available on the system.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: the problem you mention is what we (in AIX) land fondly refer to as "Dependency hell" - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell for a nice right up.

**ANSWER**:
Michael Perzl gives his solution here: http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php?n=FAQs.FAQs#rpm-dependency-hell - this is probably where you will find the dependencies you are looking for.

Note: for svn I have been using jsvn (java based version) - as I found it too troublesome to download and install an official version - because of dependency hell.